# Python - convert a raw binary dump into ASCII HEX bytes

Tags: python, binary, ascii

Further to this question: [Handling and working with binary data HEX with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574587/handling-and-working-with-binary-data-hex-with-python)  (and thanks to awesome pointers I received) I'm stuck on one last aspect of tool.

I am basically writing a cleaner for files that I have with data past the EOF marker. This extra data means they fail some validation tools. I need to strip the extra data, so they be presented to the validator, however I don't want to throw this data away (in fact I have to keep it...)

I've written an XML container to hold the data, and a few other provenance/audit type values, but I'm (still) stuck on elegantly moving between raw binary and something I can "bake" in to a file.

example:

A jpg file ends with (hex editor view)
`96 1a 9c fd ab 4f 9e 69 27 ad fd da 0a db 76 bb
ee d2 6a fd ff 00 ff d9 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff`

The EOF marker for jpg is `ff d9`, so the cleaner works backwards through the file until its a match against the EOF marker. In this case it would create a new jpg file stopping at the `ff d9` and then attempt to write the stripped data to the XML (via the elementTree lib): `changeString.text =str(excessData)`

Of course this wont work as the XML writer is looking to write ASCII not binary dumps.

In the above case, the error is `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)` which I can see if because its not a valid ASCII character

My question therefore, is how do I elegantly deal with this raw data, in a way it can stored and used in the future? (I plan to write an 'uncleaner' next that can take the clean file and the XML and reconstruct the original file...)

______EDIT_______

Using the suggestions from below, this is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\EOF_cleaner\scripts\test6.py", line 87, in <module> main()
  File "C:\...\EOF_cleaner\scripts\test6.py", line 73, in main splitFile(f_data, offset)
  File "C:\...EOF_cleaner\scripts\test6.py", line 60, in splitFile makeXML(excessData)
  File "C:\...\EOF_cleaner\scripts\test6.py", line 53 in makeXML ET.ElementTree(root).write(noteFile)
  File "c:\python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 815, in write serialize(write, self._root, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
  File "c:\python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 934, in _serialize_xml_serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
  File "c:\python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 934, in _serialize_xml_serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
  File "c:\python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 934, in _serialize_xml_serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
  File "c:\python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 932, in _serialize_xml write(_escape_cdata(text, encoding))
  File "c:\python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1068, in _escape_cdata  return text.encode(encoding, "xmlcharrefreplace")
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The line that throws things is `changeString.text = excessData.encode('base64')` (line 45) and `ET.ElementTree(root).write(noteFile)` (line 53)

Comment: Tried to write `unicode(str(excessData))` ?

Comment: @MahmoudAladdin Thanks, but that gives the same error!

Comment: Your traceback shows that something *else* is adding binary data to your tree *too*. If you disable the `changeString.text` line altogether, do you still get the error?

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are of course correct :(  Time to go hunting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64):

```
excessData.encode('base64')
```

It'll be easy to turn that back to binary data later on with a simple `.decode('base64')` call.

Base64 encodes to ASCII data safe for inclusion in XML, in a reasonably compact format; every 3 bytes of binary information become 4 Base64 characters.

Comment: Thank you, That looks simple enough... I tried placing that line verbatim after the line that declares the excessData variable ( `excessData = f_data[offset:]` but I still get the UnicodeDecode error. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: @JayGattuso, the `encode` doesn't modify the data in-place, it returns a new string. You probably want `excessData = f_data[offset:].encode('base64')`

Comment: `changeString.text = excessData.encode('base64')` should work; `.encode()` returns the encoded value, it doesn't change the string in-place.

Comment: Hmm, OK, so now I'm `excessData = excessData.encode('base64')`, however I still get the error - I suspect that the `changeString.text = excessData` may be trying to ASCIIify the variable?

Comment: No, it is trying to unicodify it, and that should just work since Base64 is all ASCII; all `\xff` bytes is a series of `/` slashes in Base64. What is the code and the traceback?

Comment: @JayGattuso: I cannot reproduce your issue at all using ElementTree in any case. Perhaps you have a *new* UnicodeDecodeError somewhere else?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I appreciate you looking! of the other elements that get written in the XML, the rest are all ASCII (hand written). I can see the partially built XML and see that it stops at the `changeString` element ( `<lengthOfChange>63</lengthOfChange>
            <changeString>`

Comment: @JayGattuso: File buffering means not all of the XML will have been written; that's no indication.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it turns out I am an idiot... - your suggestion works perfectly. Thank you for your time. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to have been of assistance. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To convert raw bytes to space-separated ASCII hex, you can use something like:

```
>>> a = "abc\x01\x02"
>>> print(" ".join("{:02x}".format(x) for x in a))
61 62 63 01 02
```

However, as mentioned in other answers, something like Base64 is probably going to be more efficient and easier to work with.

Comment: nice, it do the same result than binascii.hexlify(a)