# Compute the checksum of an Intel Hex record in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, hex

The *Intel Hex checksum* algorithm is computed by adding a string of bytes. The last byte is the two's complement of the sum of the rest of the string, so adding it to a valid string should equal zero.

`record_block` is a byte array, read in like this:

```
file_handle = open("branson_weld_data.txt","rb")
ba = bytearray(file_handle.read())
# record_block is 20 20 00 00 00 3D 25 00 00 00 2B 02 00 85 01 00 31
# checksum is last byte, 31
```

I have not been successful in adding together the bytes of a Python byte list.

```
def verify_checksum(record_block):
    byte_sum = 0
    for byte in record_block:
        byte_sum &= b
    return byte_sum

print(verify_checksum(record_block))
    # should be zero
```

Is `record_block` a list of binary numbers? Am I adding bytes properly?

Comment: `byte_sum &= b` This is bitwise and, not addition. You might need to simulate wraparound too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the correct sum:

```
sum(record_block) & 0xff
```

but your example the checksum should be `'AB'`

Comment: Thank you. This is elegantly simple! It works, but my program does not. It seems I do not understand the difference between b"01" and b"\x01". [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574587/handling-and-working-with-binary-data-hex-with-python) is making sense.